# JSON `date(...)` to `java.Util.Date` using `org.json`

Tags: java, android, json

I'm learning Java and writing an android app that consumes a JSON object that is passed by the server.

I have it all working except the dates.

I get one of these back

```
'SomeKey':'\/Date(1263798000000)\/'
```

I am using `org.json.JSONObject`.

How do i convert `SomeKey` into a `java.Util.Date`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Date format is not standard in JSON, so you need to choose how you "pass it through". I think the value you are seeing is in millis.

In Java:

```
System.out.println (new Date(1263798000000L));
// prints: Mon Jan 18 09:00:00 IST 2010
```

This is in my timezone, of course, but in any case it is a fairly recent date.

From the javadoc of the Date constructor:

> Parameters:
>   date - the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Link to the docs here -> http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29

Comment: I'm new to ava as well, how do I do a regular expression to get the value?

Comment: You don't have to use regular expressions, you can use the String methods, to get a substring. Have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 14):

This might help:

```
public static Date JsonDateToDate(String jsonDate)
{
    //  "/Date(1321867151710)/"
    int idx1 = jsonDate.indexOf("(");
    int idx2 = jsonDate.indexOf(")");
    String s = jsonDate.substring(idx1+1, idx2);
    long l = Long.valueOf(s);
    return new Date(l);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Yoni already mentioned, JSON does not define what a date is, or how to serialize one. Looking at the JSON snippet you posted, it looks as if someone felt a little too creative, serializing a date like that.

The important thing to note here is: to any JSON parser, this is just a string. The "Date(12345)" part is meaningless. You have to parse that yourself into a `java.util.Date`, which in that case means stripping off anything that's not a number, and using the number (the UNIX time) to instantiate a `java.util.Date`.

Just for the record. A typical way to pass a date using JSON would be either

```
{'timestamp':1265231402}
```

or more likely

```
{'timestamp':'Wed, 03 Feb 2010 22:10:38 +0100'}
```

The latter example would be the current timestamp (as I'm writing this) using standard RFC-2822 formatting, which can easily be parsed using Java's date utilities. Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for how to parse dates in Java.

Comment: That's how .NET DateTime objects get serialised with the JsonSerialiser.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String FormartDate(String date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String datereip = date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
        Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(datereip);
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);

        String DateFmtI;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        DateFmtI = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        return DateFmtI;
    }
```